# How to get name of report used by different user in jasperserver

Tags: jasperserver

I am using jasper server enterprise version 7.0. Multiple users login to the server I can get the user name by using parameter - LoggedInUsername. But how can i get which report is used by the Logged in user. Is there any method to do so or is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a report template (JRXML), you can get its own name calling `$P{JASPER_REPORT}.getName()`:
[image: Screenshot of Jaspersoft Studio's Expression Editor, for adding built-in Parameter $P{JASPER_REPORT} to Text Field]

And this is what you see when it's published to the server (6.4.2 in my case):
[image: Screenshot of JASPER_REPORT.getName() test on JasperReports Server]
As you can see from the screenshot, the report file name and report name do not necessarily have to match.

For further details, see: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRParameter.html#JASPER_REPORT

Comment: Hi this is giving error saying $P{JASPER_REPORT}.getName() method not found

Comment: Can you add to the question a screenshot of the Text Field as defined in the JRXML, and one of the actual error?

Comment: Got It!! There was another mistake in my service.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kamal!!